# Scala type classes "view as" - cannot access method in companion object

Tags: scala, playframework, typeclass, traits

I am using the scala Enumeration type in combination with Play Framework's Reads and Writes. I would like to have a trait like:

```
trait EnumerationWrites[T <: Enumeration] {
  def reads(jsonValue: JsValue): JsResult[T] = jsonScope match {
    case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(T.withName(s)) <-- ERROR!
    case _ => JsError("String value expected")
  }
}
```

and then I would do something like

```
object MyObject extends EnumerationTrait[T]
```

This doesn't work - the compiler is not able to resolve the T type within the case matching. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: you can not call method `withName` of type parameter. You need an object.
Good news: this object could be implicit. Which you already know if you are familiar with realization of *typeclass* concept in scala.

So for general use deserializer for `Enumeration` you could use function like this:

```
implicit def enumerationReads[T <: Enumeration](implicit enum: T): Reads[enum.Value] = {
  val names: Set[String] = enum.values map (_.toString)
  Reads {
    case JsString(s) => if (names contains s) JsSuccess(enum withName s)
      else JsError(s"could not find value '$s' for $enum")
    case _ => JsError("String value expected")
  }
}
```

As you can see it demands enumeration to be implicitly available, so you should declare enumeration for this like

```
implicit case object Colors extends Enumeration {
  val Red, Blue = Value
}
```

Or provide some implicit value for your existing objects like

```
implicit val colorsEvidence = Colors
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not able to make it work. I would appreciate it if you could elaborate some more - or maybe point to a gist.

Comment: @ticofab here the worksheet i used for this answer https://gist.github.com/Odomontois/ba6960981ca3989a84e4